# Azure App service Test Automation with C# and selinium

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, test-plan

I've created CI&CD on Azure repo, and it is doing code deployment on App service.

Now created Automation that opens the browsers and do actions and generates reports for test cases. (C#+Selenium+report package).

Now I need to the setup Test plan, I know, needs to run headless testing, my the questions are

1. need to do without buying a Test plan package, then how we should do? (I have a subscription but not with test plans)
2. How to do using Azure Test plans (any recent blog pls, and no MS docs links).

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can execute Selenium tests directly in the pipeline(Without test plan).

Here are the steps:

1. Add `Visual Studio Test Task` to run the Selenium tests and the test result will be output to the Test tab(Build Pipeline or Release Pipeline).
2. You also could use [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to publish test result.

[image]

Here is a blog about the detailed steps: [Automating Selenium Tests in Azure Pipelines](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/).

**For headless testing,**

You could refer to [UI testing considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#headless-mode-or-visible-ui-mode).

By the way, since  you have already created CI/CD, you can also consider integrating UI testing steps into CI/CD.

If you still want to configure test plan, you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops).

Comment: @Praveen. Feel free to let me konw if the answer could  give you some help.